# form_set_error highlight offending field?

Tags: 6, forms

form_set_error supposedly takes the name of the offending form element as the first param.

I have a form element that is named "field_reviewer_terms_of_service[value]" (as taken from firebug). My code that sets the error is:

```
    form_set_error('field_reviewer_terms_of_service[value]', t('You must agree to the Terms of Service.'));
```

The error shows up in the messages, but doesn't highlight the form element itself. What am I doing wrong?

Edited with HTML of form element:

```
<div id="edit-field-applicant-terms-of-service-value-wrapper" class="form-item">
 <label for="edit-field-applicant-terms-of-service-value" class="option"><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox required error" value="1" id="edit-field-applicant-terms-of-service-value" name="field_applicant_terms_of_service[value]"> I agree to the <a href="/terms_of_service" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the `[value]` inside, it should work with only

```
form_set_error('field_reviewer_terms_of_service', t('You must agree to the Terms of Service.'));
```

See the documentation for [`form_set_error()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error/6).
You may have to use some `[value` inside your field if it is multivalued, see this [comment](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error/6#comment-15099) but we need to see the HTML ouput for your field.

Comment: I tried it without the [value] but it still didn't work. I edited the question with the HTMLs.

Comment: Hum I'm not really sure why is this happening, I set up a single on/off checkbox (as you appear to have) and it works fine with just the fieldname. However with multiple checkbox it doesn't work but there's a module to correct this: [checkbox validate](http://drupal.org/project/checkbox_validate). Have you looked at modules like [legal](http://drupal.org/project/legal) or [terms of use](http://drupal.org/project/terms_of_use) ?

Comment: I may have to fall back on those modules. I didn't think I'd need a module just to add a required checkbox. :P